# How can I redirect unrecognized URLs in an MVC web application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect

The problem we are currently experiencing is that we have been assigned IP addresses on azure which were previously used for something else and so there are out of date domains which are still calling this IP address from within another web application.  This is causing a few problems in our app and what we want to do is redirect any calls which aren't from our app's URLs (i.e. coming from the out of date domains) to a 403.  This isn't really a security issue at the moment, just a speed issue as all these extra calls are dragging the system down.

I have tried to redirect from within the MvcHandler in routing as we really don't want the calls getting any further, however every attempt I make here just results in errors such as "Server cannot append header after HTTP headers have been sent", so I don't think this correct at all:

```
  protected override IAsyncResult BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase     httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
  {
     if (condition)
     {

        httpContext.Response.Status = "403 Forbidden";
        httpContext.Response.StatusCode = 403;
        httpContext.Response.Redirect(httpContext.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri
           .Replace(httpContext.Request.Url.AbsolutePath, "/Central/Error/Forbidden"), true);
        return base.BeginProcessRequest(
           httpContext, callback, state);
     }
```

The forbidden action is just a basic error screen, but ideally I'd like the default 403 error view to be shown.

Is there a better place for me to be doing this?  The only examples of redirecting to 403 that I can find are in the controllers, but we don't want it to get that far as we have a lot of custom code in place before it gets there.

Comment: Use IIS Url Rewriting instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of catching on 403 (which you should do anyway as a part of error handling), I suggest you do filtering on domain name: if request comes to a domain name that you don't own, give them <s>a finger</s> 403.

```
public class ClientDomainFilter : IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("filterContext");
        }

        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsLocal)
        {
            //for local development
            return;
        }

        // if no redirection domain is specified, can't do anything, don't redirect
        var clientDomain = "example.com"
        var requestedDomain = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.Host;
        var rawUrl = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl;

        // request is from the correct domain. Stop doing any work
        if (String.Equals(clientDomain, requestedDomain, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            return;
        }


        // request is from the wrong domain
        // Creaate a response with 403. 
        // Don't do redirect though, as the redirect status code is 302, not 403
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The problem is, I need to catch this in BeginProcessRequest, or before as I don't want it to do any of that processing, so an Authorization Filter would be too late.

I need to be able to say that, as soon as the request hits the RouteHandler to just throw it out and send it to a 403 without running through any of my code.  But every solution I have seen requires the code to still get to the controller and run through the controller method before redirecting to 403.

Any ideas?

Comment: Then do url rewrite in web.config. As far as I know this will not even get to your code.

Comment: @KFR42 so MVC filter worked for you? Or you went down the url-rewriting route?

Answer (score 0):

As it says in the error, the header information is already been written before you can redirect. Try clearing the headers first using    `Response.ClearHeaders();`

Comment: This works, to an extent.  It still won't allow redirecting, but as I don't think I can do that as trailmax mentions that is technically a 302.

The problem I am having now is that if you set the status to 403, it still goes to the controller and loads the page before redirecting.  This gives a load of errors in my local code.  Is there any way I can just skip straight to a 403 screen and not go through the controller?